R: Problems installing older versions of packages because company blocks github.com
I want to install older versions of R packages for reproducibility reasons, e.g., openssl v2.2.1
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/openssl/openssl_2.2.1.tar.gz")
My company blocks github.com, hence I get the following error messages as some older packages need to re-install older versions of the programs they wrap. See below my error message:
Error: Error installing package 'openssl':
===================================

* installing *source* package 'openssl' ...
** Paket 'openssl' erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** using staged installation
** libs
using C compiler: 'gcc.exe (GCC) 13.2.0'
"C:/Users/XXX/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-44~1.1/bin/x64/Rscript.exe" "../tools/winlibs.R"
Fehler in download.file(url, basename(url), quiet = TRUE) : 
  kann URL 'https://github.com/r-windows/bundles/releases/download/openssl-3.3.0/openssl-3.3.0-ucrt-x86_64.tar.xz' nicht öffnen
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldungen:
1: In download.file(url, basename(url), quiet = TRUE) :
  heruntergeladene Länge 0 != angegebene Länge 15499
2: In download.file(url, basename(url), quiet = TRUE) :
  cannot open URL 'https://github.com/r-windows/bundles/releases/download/openssl-3.3.0/openssl-3.3.0-ucrt-x86_64.tar.xz': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
Ausführung angehalten
make: *** [Makevars.win:24: winlibs] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'openssl'
* removing 'C:/Users/XXX/Tools/YYY/renv/staging/1/openssl'
install of package 'openssl' failed [error code 1]

Is there maybe a possibility of defining a mirror? Or is there something else that I might have overlooked?
Bioconductor is blocked, too, but CRAN works fine.

It's trying to install the system dependency. Here's the script that the installer is running: https://github.com/jeroen/openssl/blob/master/tools/winlibs.R. I am not aware of any mirrors that contain that exact expected library. Maybe you can get your IT department to download it for you.

If you can't find openssl 3.3.0 somewhere else (seems like that's the case) you're stuck; your employer is preventing you from doing your job. You can try to download the software in your coffee break or at home using a different network or ask for a temporary gateway, if you want to jump through the extra loops.

Posit Public Package manager & dated snapshots? https://packagemanager.posit.co/client/#/ , install.packages("openssl", repos = c(CRAN = "https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/2024-09-19"))

@margusl Thanks! Unfortunately, posit.co is also blocked :(
